# How to get values from angular dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Drop down

**HTML**

```
<select data-ng-model='datasource.value' ng-options='sourcetype.dataSourceType as sourcetype.dataSourceDesc for sourcetype in sourcetypes' data-ng-change="getAccountCredentials(sourcetype);">
    <option disabled value="" selected>Choose One</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.getAccountCredentials = function(data){      
    console.log(data);  
}
```

I am not able to get selected values .

Please suggest angular way to do this

Comment: selected value is $scope.datasource.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already binding your selected value to `datasource.value` with `data-ng-model='datasource.value'`

Try removing `data-ng-change="getAccountCredentials(sourcetype);"`:

```
<select data-ng-model='datasource.value' ng-options='sourcetype.dataSourceType as sourcetype.dataSourceDesc for sourcetype in sourcetypes'>
    <option disabled value="" selected>Choose One</option>
</select>
```

And just use $watch to watch your `datasource.value`

```
$scope.$watch("datasource.value",function(newValue){      
    console.log(newValue);  
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works great. Is there any other way to do this because i read some were ,watch should not use in controllers

Comment: @prash: Why $watch should not be used inside controllers? I think $watch works great if you need a central place to watch for model changes. Think about when you bind the `datasource.value` to more than 1 place and you need to be notified when the value changes no matter from which control.

Comment: @prash: you could still use your ng-change by passing `datasource.value` to it: `data-ng-change="getAccountCredentials(datasource.value);"`

Comment: but using this ng-change i am not able to get all values , some values are getting and some are missing

Comment: using watch i am able to get all the values

Comment: @prash: hmm, It could be that `ng-model` does not update the `datasource.value` yet when `ng-change` evaluates. Why don't you just use $watch?